# Choosing a suitable model for metabolomics data with categorical predictors and a continuous outcome

Tags: regression, categorical-data

I have a small preclinical cohort of mice and want to check the alterations in metabolites measured by mass spectroscopy. Classically the metabolomics data is first log transformed then extreme outliers were removed. Metabolomics data usually involve correlated variables(metabolites). My predictors are genotype (2 levels) and age; used once as continuous variable (age in weeks) and once as categorial variable (group: 3 levels).

I fit the models in R as follows:

```
lm(scale(x ,scale = do.scale) ~ factor(genotype) + age_wks, data = X)
lm(scale(x ,scale = do.scale) ~ factor(genotype) + factor(group), data = X)
```

My question: is the 2nd model correct to interpret using summary (t-values and p-values) or I should use the F-stats from car::Anova(type III). All the p-values are then fdr corrected.